# Getting the total number of records in PagedList

Tags: t-sql, pagedlist

The datagrid that I use on the client is based on SQL row number; it also requires a total number of pages for its paging. I also use the PagedList on the server.

SQL Profiler shows that the PagedList makes 2 db calls - the first to get the total number of records and the second to get the current page. The thing is that I can't find a way to extract that total number of records from the PagedList. Therefore, currently I have to make an extra call to get that total which creates 3 calls in total for each request, 2 of which are absolutely identical. I understand that I probably won't be able to rid of the call to get the totals but I hate to call it twice. Here is an extract from my code, I'd really appreciate any help in this:

```
var t = from c in myDb.MyTypes.Filter<MyType>(filterXml) select c;
response.Total = t.Count(); // my first call to get the total

double d = uiRowNumber / uiRecordsPerPage;
int page = (int)Math.Ceiling(d) + 1;

var q = from c in myDb.MyTypes.Filter<MyType>(filterXml).OrderBy(someOrderString)
    select new ReturnType
    {
        Something = c.Something
    };

response.Items = q.ToPagedList(page, uiRecordsPerPage);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PagedList has a .TotalItemCount property which reflects the total number of records in the set (not the number in a particular page). Thus response.Items.TotalItemCount should do the trick.